# Retrieve an array containing a BSON document

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve an array containing a BSON document using `C#`. Below is the document structure and the code that I'm using in order to do that.

```
"_id": 199,
    "name": "Rae Kohout",
    "scores": [{
        "type": "exam",
        "score": 82.11742562118049
    },
    {
        "type": "quiz",
        "score": 49.61295450928224
    },
    {
        "type": "homework",
        "score": 28.86823689842918
    },
    {
        "type": "homework",
        "score": 5.861613903793295
    }]
}



var db = client.GetDatabase("school");
var studentCol = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("students");
var builderDoc = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;                       
var filter=builderDoc.ElemMatch("scores", builderDoc.Eq("type","homework" ));
var result = studentCol.Find(filter);
```

When I execute this statement, the value of the result is coming as `{find({ "scores" : { "$elemMatch" : { "type" : "homework" } } })}`. If I apply `.tolist()`, I am seeing the data coming properly, but as a generic collection, where I'm not able to do any mongo querying on it.

How can I retrieve the document as an array?

Comment: ah typical assignment work. I'd suggest read your course documents andpay close attention and you'll get it.

Comment: ha ha ha yes my friend you are right. it is not about assignment and I don't mind if I'm able to submit the assignment on time or not. I'm trying to gain some knowledge on how this can be done. Let me go through all the tutorials once again to see if I can find any concept that I may have missed. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yep, this is the only way  to learn something.